# How to test React Native components on a custom OS other than Android and iOS?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, automated-tests

My company has a custom OS of it's own and we have built multiple React Native components to run on this OS. My task is to find several techniques to test these components on this custom OS. Would Jest work for this matter? What would be the best approach for me to test such an OS? Any insight would be most greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is an Electron based app using something like [this](https://github.com/react-everywhere/re-start/tree/react-16).

Otherwise you have to write your own adapter implementation, you have to study the react native architecture and write the native equivalent for your OS.